# Convert raw date to ordinal integer in R

Tags: r, date, integer

I have data frame with dates and I want to convert dates to ordinal integers,

```
> glimpse(df)
Observations: 211,797
Variables: 42
   $ Churn                  <fct> No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No…
    $ min_date               <date> 2017-02-13, 2017-02-13, 2017-02-13, 2017-02-13, 2017-02-13, 2017-02-13, 2017-02-13, 2017-02-13, 2017-02-13, 2…
    $ min_NoPaid_date        <date> 2017-02-13, 2017-02-13, 2017-02-13, 2017-02-13, 2017-02-13, 2017-02-13, 2017-02-13, 2017-02-13, 2017-02-13, 2…
    $ min_paid_date          <date> 2017-02-27, 2017-02-27, 2017-02-27, 2017-02-27, 2017-02-27, 2017-02-27, 2017-02-27, 2017-02-27, 2017-02-27, 2…
    $ max_date               <date> 2019-05-14, 2019-05-14, 2019-05-14, 2019-05-14, 2019-05-14, 2019-04-27, 2019-05-14, 2019-05-14, 2019-05-14, 2…
    $ max_NoPaid_date        <date> 2017-02-26, 2017-02-26, 2017-02-26, 2017-02-26, 2017-02-26, 2019-04-27, 2017-02-26, 2017-02-26, 2017-02-26, 2…
    $ max_paid_date          <date> 2019-05-14, 2019-05-14, 2019-05-14, 2019-05-14, 2019-05-14, 2019-04-26, 2019-05-14, 2019-05-14, 2019-05-14, 2…


> str(df)
    Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  211797 obs. of  42 variables:
9173842 11288931 9167070 4310995 11289083 8816781 ...
     $ Churn                 : Factor w/ 2 levels "No","Yes": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 359 360 361 362 363 364 365 366 367 368 ...
     $ min_date              : Date, format: "2017-02-13" "2017-02-13" "2017-02-13" ...
     $ min_NoPaid_date       : Date, format: "2017-02-13" "2017-02-13" "2017-02-13" ...
     $ min_paid_date         : Date, format: "2017-02-27" "2017-02-27" "2017-02-27" ...
     $ max_date              : Date, format: "2019-05-14" "2019-05-14" "2019-05-14" ...
     $ max_NoPaid_date       : Date, format: "2017-02-26" "2017-02-26" "2017-02-26" ...
     $ max_paid_date         : Date, format: "2019-05-14" "2019-05-14" "2019-05-14" ...
```

I tried to make a function to apply all date columns.

```
date_to_integer <- function(x) {
                        y = as.integer(format(as.Date(x), "%Y%m%d"))
                        y
    }


churn_data_tbl[4:9] <- lapply(churn_data_tbl, date_to_integer)
```

However, I get `Error in charToDate(x) : character string is not in a standard unambiguous format`.

Could someone help me how I can get around this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `format` is an argument to `as.Date()`. You want `as.integer(as.Date(x, format = "%Y%m%d"))`, not `as.integer(format(as.Date(x), "%Y%m%d"))`. Also, make sure you apply it to just your Date columns. You presumably want `churn_data_tbl[4:9] <- lapply(churn_data_tbl[4:9], date_to_integer)`, using `4:9` inside the `lapply` too.

Comment: **But**, your structure shows that the columns *are already `Date` class*. So you don't need the `as.Date` at all, just `churn_data_tbl[4:9] <- lapply(churn_data_tbl[4:9], as.integer)`.

Comment: @Gregor thanks very much indeed, however using the second option as you suggested, I don't get a right date as integers. I get  for `date  2017-02-13`  something like this `17210`

Comment: Yes, that's how dates are stored and how they are converted to integers---the number of days since 1970-01-01. Can you explain what you **do** want? You say "ordinal integers", so I assume you want them starting from 1... but (a) do you want each column starting from 1 independently, or do you want a single ranking for all columns? (b) How do you want to handle ties? If the input dates are `2019-01-01, 2019-01-02, 2019-01-02, 2019-01-03`, do you want the result to be `1, 2, 2, 3`, `1, 2, 2, 4`, or something else?

Comment: @Gregor sorry, maybe I could not explain it well. say I have 2017-01-01 and I want it like this 20170101. cheers –

Comment: Okay, then edit your function to remove `as.Date()` because they are already dates. `date_to_integer <- function(x) {as.integer(format(x, "%Y%m%d"))}`, and specify the correct columns to apply to: `churn_data_tbl[4:9] <- lapply(churn_data_tbl[4:9], date_to_integer)`. Your error was probably due to attempting to apply the function to the first column, which isn't a date.

Comment: And next time, please show a little bit of the desired output in your question to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Gregor It did work. I will take into acount your suggesttion for next time. thanks bery much